# Was music considered to be a part of forbidden Greek philosophy?

Tags: talmud-gemara, music

Starting with Pythagoras (c.500BCE) and Plato (c.400BCE) music was considered wisdom and as such, an integral part of Greek philosophy (see ["Music of ancient Greece and philosophy WIKI"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_ancient_Greece#Music_and_philosophy)).

On the other hand, there are numerous Talmudic prohibitions of studying Greek philosophy (see ["היחס ללימודים כלליים במקורות חז"ל"](https://cms.education.gov.il/EducationCMS/Units/Jerusalem/PeiluyotBaMachoz/AgapeyGil/YchasLelimudim.htm).

In our sources, was the systematic study of music (as opposed to recreational playing) ever considered forbidden?

Comment: You can add the gemara in Chagiga 15b about Acher always singing Greek songs.

Comment: https://thelehrhaus.com/scholarship/secular-music-and-the-jewish-soul/

Comment: @Shmuel a very interesting and informative article, thank you.